# To describe something as a 'quarter' or 'half' of something do they need to be of a certain size?

Tags: terminology, technical

If I split something into two unequally sized pieces can I say for example, this is 'my half', or I have the 'bigger half' of a cake? I hear this a lot with natural English speakers. If I split something into three pieces, with one having 25% of the area, such as a pie chart, I would take the section with 25% of the area and call it a 'quarter' of the chart, no matter if there are three pieces. Is it based on what percentage of the whole is divided or how many parts it is split into?

Comment: Yes, looking at your words, a  quarter of the chart, 25% or so, measures against the chart regardless of other pieces. Also, my half of the cake could be 40% and I'd still claim it as my portion. So my half, in common terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both uses are valid and commonly used, much to the annoyance of mathematicians.

It is absolutely normal to call something that is 25% of the whole "a quarter", even if the whole was not divided into four pieces.

> I cut the cake into three pieces - a half for Adam, and a quarter each for Beatrice and Charles.

However it is also normal for "half" and "quarter" to be approximate. If you cut the cake into four similar pieces you can refer to them as "quarters", even if they are not exactly the same size.

There is even a joke about it:

> Will the students studying remedial math please use the larger half of the hall.

Comment: I assume the less precise definition of 'quarter' is only used if there are exactly four pieces?

Comment: Yes. You would not use the term unless either it was one of four pieces or it was about a quarter the size of the original.

Answer (score 0):

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/half)
> half:
> either of the two equal or nearly equal parts that together make up a whole

Similarly, Merriam Webster has

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half)
> half:
> either of two equal parts that compose something
> also:
> a part approximately equal to one of these
> *half the distance*
> *the larger half of the fortune*

These and other dictionary definitions exemplify two accepted uses of *half*:
exactly a half, equal to the other half;
and
about a half, approximately equal to the other half.

The degree of approximation or near equality is not defined, leaving the word open to interpretation from context.

Similar arguments apply to *third*, which may be understand as about a third of the whole.

Pragmatically, the only constraint on the approximation is that the total of two halves must equal the whole, and the total of the three thirds must equal the whole.